# batch/power shell script to create folders based on file name and move files

Tags: batch-file

I have couple of files with names like "Axis_Master Group_First_Report_201312.xlsx",
Axis_Master Group_second_Report_201312.xlsx. 
I need a script to read the file name and based on the file name, create folders and move files into that folder. 
In the above example, i need the first file to be moved into a folder with the name Axis and with in Axis, it should be moved to a folder First .
For the second file, it need to be moved to the same Axis folder but it should be moved into a new folder "second". 
please help. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I assume all files match `*_*_*_*.xlsx`, and you want the first and third tokens using `_` as a delimiter.

The first FOR simply iterates all the matching files. The subsequent FOR /F parses out the first and third tokens. It never hurts to repeatedly attempt to create the folder(s) multiple times. I simply hide any error message by redirecting stderr to nul.

```
@echo off
for %%F in (*_*_*_*.xlsx) do for /f "tokens=1,3 delims=_" %%A in ("%%F") do (
  md "%%A\%%B" 2>nul
  move "%%F" "%%A\%%B"
)
```

Comment: I'd improve the pattern to `?*_*_?*_*.xlsx` or even to `?*_?*_?*_*.xlsx` (and `delims=_"` instead of `delims=_'` :))

Comment: Yep - there was a typo in my DELIMS spec. Thanks. I don't see the addition of `?` as much of an improvement. I suppose it guarantees at least one character between the underscores, but that character could be another underscore, which would still create problems. If you really want to get a precise file mask then switch outer loop to FOR /F executing DIR /B piped to FINDSTR with an appropriate regex. But in all likelyhood, my original code will work fine for the OP.

Answer (score 0):

This code moves all files matching the pattern `"Axis_Master Group_$1_$2.$3"` into a folder `axis\$1` and renames it to `$2.$3`.

```
@echo off
md axis > Nul <&2
for %%a in ("Axis_Master Group_*_*.*") do (
    call :refolder "%%a"
)
exit /b

:refolder
set fileName=%~n1
set fileName=%fileName:Axis_Master Group_=%
for /f "delims=_ tokens=1*" %%a in ("%fileName%") do (
    md axis\%%a > Nul <&2
    move /y %1 axis\%%a\%%b%~x1 > Nul <&2
)
exit /b
```

Comment: Thank you. That helped. Got it working with this script.
@echo off       
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=c:\Src"
PUSHD %sourcedir%
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=_" %%i in ('dir /b /a-d *_*.xlsx') do (
mkdir "%%i" >nul
mkdir "%%i/%%j" >nul
mkdir "%%i/%%j/%%k"  >nul
move "%%i_*.xlsx" "%%i/%%j/%%k" >NUL
)